# SAS Is it possible not to use "TO" in a do loop in MACRO?

Tags: sas

I used to use a `%do ... %to` and it worked fine , but I when I tried to list all character values without  `%to` I got a message  `ERROR: Expected %TO not found in %DO statement`

```
%macro printDB2 ; 
%let thisName = ;
%do &thisName = 'Test1' , 'Test2' , 'Test3' ;
proc print data=&thisName ;
run ;
%end ;
%mend printDB2 ;
```

I know how to complete this task using `%to` or `%while` . But I am curious is it possible to list all character values in the `%do` ? How can I %do this ?

Comment: According to the documentation http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543755.htm `%TO` is required. Why do you think it would work without `%TO`?

Comment: in a data step one can use `do` without `to` , just listing all values  separated by commas . So i thought may be in MACRO one can do the same

Comment: The data step do statement is completely different from the macro %do. So I don't think you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal here is to loop through a series of character values in some macro logic, one approach you could take is to define corresponding sequentially named macro variables and loop through those, e.g.

```
%let mvar1 = A;
%let mvar2 = B;
%let mvar3 = C;

%macro example;
    %do i = 1 %to 3;
        %put mvar&i = &&mvar&i;
    %end;
%mend example;

%example;
```

Alternatively, you could scan a list of values repeatedly and redefine the same macro var multiple times within your loop:

```
%let list_of_values = A B C;

%macro example2;
    %do i = 1 %to 3;
        %let mvar = %scan(&list_of_values, &i, %str( ));
        %put mvar = &mvar;
    %end;
%mend example2;

%example2;
```

I've explicitly specified that I want to use space as the only list delimiter for scan - otherwise SAS uses lots default delimiters.